# Peticiones HTTP desde Firebase Functions(NodeJS)

Tags: javascript, nodejs, firebase

Quiero realizar una función desde Firebase Functions, pero realizando una autorización a otro servicio, que introduciéndole los parámetros de usuario y contraseña en el caso de ser correctos, devuelve una lista de empresas del usuario. Si realizo este proceso desde Postman me lo devuelve todo correcto, he usado el generador de código que tiene Postman para generar este código que he metido en mi función de firebase Functions(nodeJS) de esta forma:

```js
function autorizacion(email: string, password: string) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        console.log("Cosas => ", email, password);

        var request = require('request');
        var options = {
          'method': 'POST',
          'url': 'http://xxx.com/api/Login',
          'headers': {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          body : '{\r\n    usuario:"' + email + '",\r\n    pwd:"' + password + '"\r\n}'
        
        };
        request(options, function (error: string | undefined, response: { body: any; }) {
          if (error) resolve(error);
          else{
              resolve(response);
          }
        });
    })
}
```

El problema viene cuando intento hacer esta petición dentro de la Firebase Functions, lo que devuelve utilizando tanto el modulo "Request" como Axios y demás son errores. El error que devuelve con el modulo request de NodeJS es:

```
{
"statusCode": 400,
"body": "",
"headers": {
    "server": "Microsoft-IIS/10.0",
    "x-powered-by": "ASP.NET",
    "date": "Mon, 28 Dec 2020 08:16:02 GMT",
    "connection": "close",
    "content-length": "0"
},
"request": {
    "uri": {
        "protocol": "http:",
        "slashes": true,
        "auth": null,
        "host": "xxx.com",
        "port": 80,
        "hostname": "xxx.com",
        "hash": null,
        "search": null,
        "query": null,
        "pathname": "/api/Login",
        "path": "/api/Login",
        "href": "http://xxx.com/api/Login"
    },
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "content-length": 63
    }
}
```

}

La url de mi api no quiero dejarla expuesta por lo tanto está sustituida por xxx. No se si es problema de mi código, o que mi api no soporta peticiones de un servidor NodeJS

Error dado con actualizacion de body

```
{
"statusCode": 302,
"body": "<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>\r\n<h2>Object moved to <a href=\"/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fapi%2fLogin\">here</a>.</h2>\r\n</body></html>\r\n",
"headers": {
    "cache-control": "private",
    "transfer-encoding": "chunked",
    "content-type": "text/html; charset=utf-8",
    "location": "/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fapi%2fLogin",
    "server": "Microsoft-IIS/10.0",
    "x-aspnet-version": "4.0.30319",
    "x-powered-by": "ASP.NET",
    "date": "Mon, 28 Dec 2020 09:26:37 GMT",
    "connection": "close"
},
"request": {
    "uri": {
        "protocol": "http:",
        "slashes": true,
        "auth": null,
        "host": "api-dev.alosuite.com",
        "port": 80,
        "hostname": "api-dev.alosuite.com",
        "hash": null,
        "search": null,
        "query": null,
        "pathname": "/api/Login",
        "path": "/api/Login",
        "href": "http://api-dev.alosuite.com/api/Login"
    },
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "content-length": 57
    }
}
```

}

RESULTADO FINAL DE LA PETICION

```
var request = require('request');
    var options = {
        'method': 'POST',
        'url': 'http://xxx.com/api/Login',
        'headers': {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        followRedirect: true,
        form: {
            'usuario': 'usuario',
            'pwd': 'password'
        }

    };
    request(options, function (error: string | undefined, response: { body: any; }) {
        if (error) resolve(error);
        resolve(response)
    });
```

Comment: Que forma tan rara de escribir el `body`. Sé que tal vez ese no es el problema (¿o si?) Prueba: `body: JSON.stringify({usuario: email, pwd: password})`. Saludos

Comment: No me ha funcionado, ahora muestra un error diferente, pero parece ser que no era eso

Comment: Actualiza tu pregunta con el nuevo error, a ver si podemos hallar el problema.

Comment: Editado, a ver que puede ver mal, la verdad que no entiendo esas respuestas de parte del servicio

Comment: La respuesta que recibes es una redirección: [`http status code 302`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/302). Significa que el recurso al que apuntas ha sido movido. Agrega la siguiente opción al objeto `options` de tu método `request`: `followRedirect: true,`. Comenta el resultado. Saludos

Comment: He probado y sigue con ese fallo, retorna el mismo resultado, no se si la petición está mal formada, o hay que cambiar alguna opcion en el servicio, o quizas utilizar cors... no tengo ni idea ahora mismo.

Comment: Parece ser que hice algo mal con las cabeceras, pondré el resultado final de la peticion para que puedas ver como ha quedado finalmente

Comment: ¿Significa que con esa solicitud funciona? Si es así, te invito a responder tu propia pregunta, explicando con detalle el problema y cómo lograste resolverlo. En resumen, aparte de la forma en que se construye el cuerpo de la solicitud y la opción de `followRedirect`, estabas enviando una petición `application/json`, cuando al parecer la API esperaba un formulario con `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. ¿Es correcto?. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

El envío de la cabecera era incorrecta, pero ademas, la api hacia un redireccion que habia que controlar, por lo tanto había que añadirle en las opciones 'followRedirect'. La peticion final queda de esta forma:

```
var request = require('request');
var options = {
    'method': 'POST',
    'url': 'http://xxx.com/api/Login',
    'headers': {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    followRedirect: true,
    form: {
        'usuario': 'usuario',
        'pwd': 'password'
    }

};
request(options, function (error: string | undefined, response: { body: any; }) {
    if (error) resolve(error);
    resolve(response)
});
```